# Iterating through JSON files and writing dict values to list

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to iterate through JSON files and save parts of the filename on a list that is stored as another JSON file. When I `print(list_of_files)` after the `append()`, I get the complete list of filenames. However, when I store it in a JSON file, I only have one entry on my list.

Here is my code:

```py
all_json = '/mypath/...'

for name_of_file in all_json:
    with open(name_of_file) as f:
        json_files = json.load(f)
        list_of_files = []
        basename = os.path.basename(name_of_file)
        name = basename[0:-9]
        list_of_files.append(name)
        print(list_of_files)
        with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(list_of_files, f, indent=4)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: you're defining `list_of_files` inside a for loop so it is overridden at every iteration.

Comment: Why do you need to reconstruct the files list when you already have it in `all_json` list? Are you trying to create a second list with just the base names? Please, post a sample of the input, the output you are getting, and the output you want.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the prompt replies and I will try to provide better MWEs in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `list_of_files` inside a for loop so it is overridden at every iteration that's why it only contains 1 element which was appended on the last iteration.

To avoid it define `list_of_files` outside the loop.

```
all_json = '/mypath/...'
list_of_files = []

for name_of_file in all_json:
    with open(name_of_file) as f:
        json_files = json.load(f)
        list_of_files = []
        basename = os.path.basename(name_of_file)
        name = basename[0:-9]
        list_of_files.append(name)
        print(list_of_files)
        with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(list_of_files, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Also accdias was right, I don't even have to load the JSON files because I'm only accessing the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer works great. Another way of achieving this goal with the current code you have is by changing how you are opening the file. You are using `with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'w') as f`. When you open the file with 'w' it will overwrite the contents of the file with whatever you are putting in it. You should be using 'a' to append instead of overwriting. `with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'a') as f:` So, overall it would be,

```
for name_of_file in all_json:
    with open(name_of_file) as f:
        json_files = json.load(f)
        list_of_files = []
        basename = os.path.basename(name_of_file)
        name = basename[0:-9]
        list_of_files.append(name)
        print(list_of_files)
        with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'a') as f:
            json.dump(list_of_files, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to create a new list using part of the file names stored in another list, and then save it in JSON format, all you have to do is:

```py
import json
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename

json_files = glob('/my/path/*.json')

base_names = list(map(basename, json_files))
base_names = [_[:-9] for _ in base_names]
with open('orderOfSamples_600.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(base_names, f, indent=4)
```